# Localizar el archivo de código desde el inspeccionador de elementos

Tags: html, css, chrome

Existe alguna forma de localizar de que archivo proviene un elemento de una web a través del inspeccionador de elementos.

Es decir, obtener la ruta del código fuente, al igual que podemos obtener la ruta del archivo css.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: En resumen, **NO**, tu cliente recibe 1 única página... pero alguien probablemente tenga más ganas de redactar más detalles y algunas excepciones en una respuesta completa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu página está construida por ejemplo, con PHP, con el inspector de código no puedes saber qué archivo (plantilla, template, partial, etc.) contiene un elemento HTML de tu web.

Te aconsejo que para eso utilices la búsqueda dentro de tu projecto. Con sublime text 3 por ejemplo, es muy fácil buscar una cadena de texto (una clase, id o similar) y que te diga en qué archivos ha encontrado esa ocurrencia.

Comment: Otra opción es que se podría estar generando dinámicamente desde JavaScript, o podría estar incluyendo otras fuentes en un iframe,

Comment: como hago una busqueda en sublime y que me localice el archivo? porque solo conozco la de ctrl F pero es busqueda en un solo archivo